# how to evaluate a javascript snippet inside android with webview

Tags: javascript, android

I have a html page on a server xyz.com

html:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
<p> Hello </p>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want to open this page in a webview in android and click that button programmatically ... so I tried a lot to do this :

js file :

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () { return "clicked"}
document.getElementById("button").click()
```

android:

```
    webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

    webview.loadUrl("xyz.com")
    webview.evaluateJavascript(jsFunction2) { s ->
        Log.d("result", s) // Prints: "this"
    }
```

It's supposed to return "clicked" but I got null... 
Any help